# Dynamics CRM - Converting Lead to Oppurtunity

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am new to CRM. I was reading [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1409780&seqNum=6) that there is a "convert lead to account, contact and opportunity". I understand how it would split the data from lead to account and contact, but I can't see ( from reading the Entity Metadata excel file ) where any opportunity information would be linked to lead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for `Originating Lead` lookup in Opportunity entity record where the Qualified Lead entity record reference will be stored.

If you want to store more Lead record values into Opportunity record, you can use entity relationship mapping like explained in [this blog](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/mapping-lead-data-new-opportunities-dynamics-365crm/).

Update:

> If you don’t want to create a Contact when qualifying, you will need to associate the Lead to an existing Contact in Dynamics CRM 2015. An Opportunity will always be created regardless of which fields are populated on the Lead.
>
> In fact, if you didn’t fill out a single field on the Lead form (none were set to ‘required’), and Qualified that Lead, you would create a new Opportunity with no information associated to a new Contact that also has no information.
>
> Of course, you can use workflows to adjust these situations as required – e.g. if you never want an Opportunity to be created from a Qualified Lead you could write a workflow to delete the Opportunity on creation (checking to make sure the Originating Lead has a value).

[Read more](https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/qualifying-leads-in-dynamics-crm-2015/)

Comment: No, I wasn't trying to link a lead to opportunity. I was trying to take a lead and convert it to an opportunity. I know I can press a button, but what is the system doing and where does it get it's information from ?

Comment: @HFoucault Read this: https://ledgeviewpartners.com/blog/qualifying-leads-in-dynamics-crm-2015/